# Does Descartes avert the divine illumination trope or play it straight?

Tags: theology, descartes

(Preamble: according to tvtropes.com, a trope can be instantiated, meaning played straight, or almost subversively instantiated, meaning averted.)

In the Book of Ezekiel, an entity known as the tetramorph appears. St. Jerome IIRC interpreted the tetramorph as a symbol of a fourfold form of moral knowledge. Like four faculties or quasi-faculties, relating to particularity and generality, reflection and application.

I'm not saying that the later doctrine of total depravity (in the Reformed theories) is strictly the claim that all four of these are damaged by sin, whereas before it was said that at least synderesis (pure abstract moral knowledge) was incorruptible. But it's a way to frame how the doctrine of divine illumination endured in history, because while (owing at last to Scotus) DDI faded from Catholic culture, it reemerged strongly in Reformed culture, as the idea that sin was so devastating of all knowledge that God alone could make knowledge possible for us in our sinful state. Maybe this isn't strictly given in Calvin, but it does appear in Cornelius van Til, hearkening back to Calvin. This is the "transcendental argument for the existence of God," and usually a specific theory of God (again especially in van Til, afaik).

Like Ayn Rand, van Til misinterprets the cogito thematically. In fact, when I first read of Descartes's opinions about the capacity for God to transcend even logical laws, and as a presupposition of all knowledge, I was surprised to remember reading van Til's opinions on Descartes as such.

But Descartes doesn't need sin to be the epistemic problem that God solves. Or, he starts from the question of divine evil, and infers that as the divine would not be evil (and is not evil as an "innate idea"), then there is a good God. At any rate, Descartes is referring more to a more plainly theoretical than practical issue, and so he has no need for divine illumination to be special revelation, here.

Does Cartesian DDI avert or play itself straight?

EDIT: DDI generally is the thesis that God is known to exist because without God, no knowledge is possible. So it is in effect the same kind of belief as the "transcendental argument for God." In Descartes, DDI appears when he says in the Meditations that he needs to suppose a good God as an epistemic protector/guarantor. There's an SEP article on an aspect of Descartes' thought in which Descartes recapitulates the transcendental argument/DDI even more clearly, almost echoing (so to say) van Til later. So why would van Til read the cogito invidiously? Like Rand, he seems to think that the inference to "I am" is causal, as if "I think" causally implies "I exist."

But the cogito is better represented as an implied epistemic sequence: "I know that I think, therefore I know that I exist." The cogito then is simultaneously an example of itself (as "if A then B") and proof of itself as a type. This is necessary because the version of the cogito in the Meditations needs to harmonize with the apriority/interiority of knowledge of God that follows in the text.

Comment: What is the question? And the connection with Descartes’ thought?

Comment: Maybe it may help to refer to SEP’entry on Divine Illumination for background.

Comment: The same using Wiki’s page in order to answer to the question: Cornelius van Til who?

Comment: Van Til was a Calvinist who proposed the transcendental argument for God (his claim: without presupposing God, nothing else is provable, so here "transcendental" is a Kantian term, though otherwise van Til was against Kant). As for DDI, yes, I was supposed to describe it on its own early but forgot that part of the post (I was working on it in my head while walking and forgot this part when I sat down to write). ---But otherwise the question is completely given here